Как работает программа выводящий собственный код на С?
Есть програмка, которая выводит свой же код:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *code = 
        "#include <stdio.h>\n\n"
        "int main() {\n"
        "    const char *code = \n"
        "        \"%s\";\n"
        "    printf(code, code);\n"
        "    return 0;\n"
        "}\n";
    printf(code, code);
    return 0;
}

Можете подробно объяснить как она работает, почему в printf() дважды передается code?
Вот как я пока что понимаю: мы первым аргументом передаем строку т.е code и внутри этой строки есть спецификатор %s и далее через запятую мы передаем ещё раз code чтобы вставить вместо этого спецификатора.

Правильно понимаете. Только тут одна беда, программка выводит почти свой код (а это не считается).

Вот тут примеры и инструкции, как делать такие программки (кстати, их зовут Quines (self-replicating programs))

@avp почти выводит свой код это из-за того что  \n не выводится

@avp или почему ?

Без цикла вряд ли получится. Без цикла, рекурсии или ещё какого-то умножения сущностей выводиться всегда будет столько, сколько зашито в строку внутри кода программы, а значит недостаточно, чтобы покрыть весь код программы, включая код вокруг этой строки. )

мда... то, что на python делается в 80 символов на C занимает довольно много, возможно, на C++ можно покороче...

@AslanPAPA, да, символы \n, кавычек и т.п. Вы просто diff-ом сравните

@CrazyElf, думаю что квайн без цикла и рекурсии возможен.
